# Upload a contact image via the API

Tags: contacts, api, images, files

Can someone give me a simple example of how to upload a Contact image via the API? I am guessing it will involve a call to the File API as well but not sure.

I have the original image as a URL but want to store it in CiviCRM (not just reference the URL).

Bonus points for a nicely commented answer :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contact Image URL is directly stored in `civicrm_contact` table, so I think if you have the URL which can display an image, you should be directly able to use the contact create API as below -

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'create', array(
  'contact_type' => "Individual",
  'first_name' => "first",
  'last_name' => "last",
  'image_URL' => "<url>",
));
```

If you're on version < 5.0, the contact summary page will render the image only iff the URL is in form of `http://site-name/civicrm/contact/imagefile?photo=imageName.jpg` and your image file should be present in your custom file upload directory.

There is now a [patch(included in version 5.0)](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11681) which allows the contact summary page to display any URL image irrespective of the `photo` param in the URL.

If you want to download a copy of a remote image to your local file system and use that, you could do something along the lines of:

```
$contactId = 123;
$imageName = 'jitendra.jpg';
$path = Civi::paths()->getPath(Civi::settings()->get('customFileUploadDir')) . $imageName;
file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents('https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjnic.jpg'));
civicrm_api3('Contact', 'create', [
  'id' => $contactId,
  'image_URL' => CRM_Utils_System::url('civicrm/contact/imagefile', ['photo' => $imageName], true)
]);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, Jitendra, very helpful. I still have one outstanding question though. How would I upload an image file so that it is available at http://site-name/civicrm/contact/imagefile?photo=imageName.jpg?

Comment: Also, I played around with file uploading via the UI and the image URL was reported as `http://chatbot.buildkit:8080/civicrm/file?reset=1&filename=michael_ed7e440cde7726911615c9e97042b177.png&mime-type=image/png`. I was expecting something similar to `http://site-name/civicrm/contact/imagefile...` - any thoughts on that?

Comment: May I know the CiviCRM version you are testing on? I guess contact upload uses that URL in the older versions.

Comment: If you don't have the image file available in the custom upload directory - you can apply the PR mentioned in the answer and fed the URL to the image_url param in the API. Note the URL should be able to display an image.

Comment: OK, I think I get it now. I have added an example to your answer to clarify my particular use case. Do you want to have a look and let me know what you think?

Comment: PS I was on 4.7.32 / 5.0